# Why is sort() using SORT_NUMERIC in reverse order in PHP 7?

Tags: php, sorting, quicksort

If I use `sort()` using `SORT_NUMERIC` like this:

```
<?php

$array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

sort($array1, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($array1);
```

The output is in PHP 5.5/5.6 in increasing order (as expected):

> Array ( [0] => img1.png [1] => img2.png [2] => img10.png [3] => img12.png )

But in PHP 7 it is in reverse order:

> Array ( [0] => img12.png [1] => img10.png [2] => img2.png [3] => img1.png )

So why is `sort()` using `SORT_NUMERIC` in PHP 7 in reverse order?

Comment: You're trying to sort non-numeric values, so it's sorting by numeric approximation of 
 a "string". In your case, all values are the "same" numeric number. By PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php, If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined. PHP5.6 and PHP7 have different internal ordering, but as it's undefined, they're not promising the same response.

Comment: "_So why is sort() using SORT_NUMERIC in PHP 7 in reverse order?_" Is it? That's the original order of your array values. Try changing the order of your values and see if you still get the "reverse order".

Answer (score 2):

Because the array values are not strictly numerical, PHP 7 does not sort at all in this case.

```
<?php
$array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img2.png", "img10.png", "img1.png");
sort($array1, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($array1);
```

> Array ( [0] => img12.png [1] => img2.png [2] => img10.png [3] => img1.png )

```
<?php
$array1 = $array2 = array("12", "2", "10", "1");
sort($array1, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($array1);
```

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 10 [3] => 12 )

Use `natsort()` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: Why not `sort` with `SORT_NATURAL` flag?

Comment: Yes, that has the same effect according to documentation

Comment: This answers your question how?  Your question was why is it different in PHP7.  So, why is it different?

Answer (score 1):

$array1 =  array("img10.png","img12.png",  "img2.png", "img1.png");

sort($array1,SORT_NATURAL);

print_r($array1);

will give result 
Array ( [0] => img1.png [1] => img2.png [2] => img10.png [3] => img12.png )

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rsort()` function, it displays members of an array in the "right" order.